# rust single liners inside structs

Tags: rust, struct

Is it possible to have one line assignments in structs as an example:

```
pub struct Pipe {
    texture: Texture2D,
    
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}
```

Instead have something like

```
pub struct Pipe {
    texture: Texture2D,

    (x, y): (f32, f32)
}
```

Also an approach like this is not what I want, because I want to access the variable like Pipe.pos.x or Pipe.x instead of pipe.pos.0:

```
pub struct Pipe {
    texture: Texture2D,

    pos: (f32, f32)
}
```

Comment: If you want `pipe.pos.x`, you should define a `struct Pos { x: f32, y: f32 }` and use `pos: Pos` in `Pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have one line assignments in structs as an example:

No.

> Also an approach like this is not what I want, because I want to access the variable like Pipe.pos.x or Pipe.x instead of pipe.pos.0:

Define a struct. And possibly a ctor function for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

That's called tuple

```
pub struct Pipe {
   texture: Texture2D,
   pos: (f32, f32),
}

let pipe = Pipe {
   texture: new_texture, 
   pos: (10.5, 24.0),
};

println!("x position is {}", pipe.pos.0);
println!("y position is {}", pipe.pos.1);

// to access using x and y you can create a trait
trait XYAccessor {
  fn x(&self) -> f32
  fn y(&self) -> f32
}

// implement trait for the tuple
impl XYAccessor for (f32,f32) {
   fn x(&self) -> f32 {
      self.0
   }
   fn y(&self) -> f32 {
      self.1
   }
}

// then you can use .x() and .y()
println!("x position is {}", pipe.pos.x());
println!("y position is {}", pipe.pos.y());
```

Comment: Rather than define and implement a trait, it seems simpler to just us a tuple struct and `impl` your accessors on that... That saves the entire `trait` definition a the cost of a simple `struct Pos(f32, f32)` or somesuch.